# Opening a modal (A) from another modal (B) but not opening A it when i click on the close botton of (B)

Tags: bootstrap-4

I got a modal (A) I want that when I click on a special button of that modal, a modal (B) is opening.

I've written this code :

```
$("#signUpLink").click(function() {
        $("#signIn").modal("hide");

        $('#signIn').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#signUp').modal('show')
        });
    });
```

The problem is that after the first clicking of `$("#signUpLink")` if `$("#signIn")` become hide then `$('#signUp').modal('show')` is executing.

how can I use the `.off()` jQuery method to stop the event listening of `hidden.bs.modal` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

```
function showModal(){

    $('#signUp').modal('show')

}



$("#signUpLink").click(function() {

    $("#signIn").modal("hide");

    $('#signIn').on('hidden.bs.modal', showModal);


});

$("#signInClose").click(function(){
    $('#signIn').off('hidden.bs.modal', showModal);

})
```

Comment: Help others use your answer by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55536677/edit) it to explain how the solution works.